# How to exclude special package in aar when building with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

I want to use a lib called speechkit, but it contains volley and the volley in it is not the newest version. Now, I want to use `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`。Absolutely, a multiple dex files define error happened.
I want to exclude it like the way below, but failed, error continue.

```
compile(name: 'speechkit-2.1.3', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.volley', module: 'volley'
}
```

How to exclude the volley lib in the situation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you found any solutions for that @CodeAlien ?